# confusion about timers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm a bit confused with timers in Javascript.
I've been  playing around with timers.

I'm confused with how the queuing process in asychronous events happen.
I have read about the article about how asynchronous events are queud.
But i find it hard to wrap my head around the queuing process.

Here's the code:

http://jsbin.com/iwahuf/2/edit

In the code that i have posted would the timers be queud in sequence. Wouldn't the timers in the event queue be executed FIFO (First In, First Out).

Here's what i have in mind in the event queue.

1. First Timer w/ 500ms delay
2. Second Timer w/ 600ms delay
3. Third Timer w/ 300ms delay
4. Fourth Timer w/ 400ms delay

In my opinion, since the first timer has been the first to be registered in the Event queue, it will be the first to be executed and only after 500ms will the second timer be executed and so on.

Please enlighten me on this matter. I'm a litte confused. I think my understanding of the queuing process is not quite right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Registering a timer doesn't stop your code. You're registering all timers at the same time, the scheduler will try to execute them N ms after the time of registration.

This means that

- The third timer you set will be executed first 300 ms after your main code is executed
- then it will be the fourth 400 ms after the main code was executed
- then the first and second

If you want to queue your timers, either you chain them (by making each of them call the next one) or (much lighter and simpler if the tasks are short) you compute yourself the times :

```
var time = 0;
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("First Timer");
}, time += 500);
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("Second Timer");
}, time += 600);
console.log("Executed immediately");
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("Third Timer");
}, time += 300);
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("Fourth Timer");
}, time += 400);
```

[In this somewhat related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365318/delay-to-next-function-in-method-chain/14365382#14365382) I give an implementation of a simple queue.

Comment: Right. There is no "queue of timers". If you want that, you need to implement that on your own. I.e. register the second timer within the first would add them.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I'm a little confused by your statement that they are executed at the same time. Isn't Javascript single threaded so I think only one async event or timer will be registered in the event queue.

Comment: @chanHXC well, not exactly the same time, but JS is fast enough so that it feels like the same time.

Comment: @dystroy, does that mean that the timers are executed based on delays even though another timer has been registered earlier in the queue?

Comment: Yes. all the setTimeout are executed at the same time (well, there might be one or two ms due to the code execution time) and their callbacks are scheduled counting from this time.

Answer (score 1):

No, timers are not first-in-first out.

It's not the timers themselves that are put in the event queue - when timers expire they result in a "timer elapsed" event being added to the FIFO event queue *as they expire*.

How timer objects actually detect that they've expired and create those events is out of scope, and probably implementation dependent.

Comment: i stand to be corrected here, so does that mean that the code/process inside the timer will be executed N delay, then after the timer has elapsed should the code/process be registered to the event queue unless the browser is free to execute something.

Answer (score 1):

When a timeout is set in Javascript, it does not halt execution of the following code. instead, it delays the execution of the function set to run on timeout. TO acheive your expected results, your code would need to look like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("First Timer");

  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Second Timer");

    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("Third Timer");

        setTimeout(function(){
          console.log("Fourth Timer");
        }, 400);

    }, 300);

  }, 600);

}, 500);

console.log("Executed immediately");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the response. I think you're right.
even though i'm still a little bit confused.

Comment: From your comments, it seems to me that you have a good enough understanding of computer theory to find this article useful: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/