# Javascript delay function

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a JavaScript library. I have be working on a delay function that works like this:

```
function delay(ms) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > ms){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea being that I can do something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  delay(5000);  //this function will act 5 seconds after the page loads
  document.getElementById('Header').innerHTML = 'Welcome';
};
```

The delay works fine, but it stops all javascript on the page rather than just delaying the `window.onload` function.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Don't do that ! Never never loop to wait for a condition. Use setTimeout and a queue.

Comment: That's an absolutely terrible way to do things, I'm afraid. You need to look into `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @ Pointy - Ok, I will

Comment: You won't be able to have a solution as simple as what you want. Here's [a related question with a simple queue implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365318/delay-to-next-function-in-method-chain).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question (and responses to [Patrick D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17112180/105570)) is, I *think*, based on a misunderstanding.

**There is no way to implement code that will do what you want.**

A JavaScript environment is single-threaded. (Let's ignore web workers for the moment.) This means that each line executes after the one before it.

If you have a function that occupies this (one and only) thread for 5 seconds, nothing else will run during that 5 seconds. It's as simple as that.

The way we get around this in the JavaScript world is to utilize asynchronous programming, which makes use of callbacks. The `setTimeout` function is the correct way to solve this problem.

Now, you *could* do this. Say you want a function that, given some function `fn`, returns a new function which executes `fn` after a set delay. You *could* implement this:

```
Function.prototype.delay = function(ms) {
    var fn = this;
    return function() {
        setTimeout(fn, ms);
    };
};
```

Then you could hypothetically write code like the following:

```
function foo() {
  // something or other
}

var fooDelayed = foo.delay(5000);

// Now this line will execute foo after 5 seconds.
fooDelayed();
```

If you really want something like that, it's possible. But it is still essentially a wrapper around `setTimeout`: there's no avoiding that.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfd3g/) demonstrating the idea.

Comment: Well put, thank you. You should mark this as your answer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your answer soo well, you have answered my question entirely.

Answer (score 6):

Use setTimeout instead of your delay method. It won't block the UI and is much cleaner.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById('Header').innerHTML = 'Welcome';
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't solve OP problem : he wants a delay function...

Comment: This will execute his function after a 5 second delay. What is missing?

Comment: OP says he want to build a library with a delay function...

Comment: I think what @dystroy means is, the OP wants to create **their own** delay function.

Comment: @ dystroy - It is not answering how to make a delay function.   @ Patrick D - what you're mirring is that I want to make a function that delays.

Comment: @CodeApprentice My thoughts too I've no idea why it has so many upvotes. I'm thinking people are not understanding the question too well.

Comment: Read into his question. He's asking how to delay a block of code. I doubt he literally is asking how to create an entirely new delay function, with the knowledge that `setTimeout` exists. `setTimeout` solves his problem.

Comment: Keep in mine that I am using this in a javascript library.

Comment: It would help if you described a scenario where `setTimeout` does not work for you. If given the option between choosing a native, async function like timeout, or writing your own custom code; it would make the most sense to choose the native function. If this native solution does not work, for whatever scenario, then my answer may obviously change.

Comment: What you need to understand is that JavaScript is single threaded. This matters. There is literally no code that you can write that will loop forever, without using async callbacks supported by the language, where you could achieve a delay without blocking the UI.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to build a function around `setTimeout()`, you're free to do so:

```
function delay(ms, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, ms);
}
```

There's absolutely no other way for delaying an action or execution of a code block **without** a blocking mechanism.

And because `setTimeout()` acts asynchronously, you always have to provide a callback function!

Comment: Could you give an example of how this would be used.

Comment: This solution is the same as my answer, it just abstracts out a single parameter. You will STILL have to use callbacks in either scenario. It's exactly the same.

Comment: @PatrickD Absolutely! I can't understand the OP's reasons for the need of this redundant function either. +1 for you btw.