# Add a sleep method in a object method chain(JS)

Tags: javascript, settimeout, method-chaining

I'm trying to add a sleep method in a object, which can be called in the middle of a method chain. I considered to use the setTimeout(), but the javascript thread could not be blocked, and it can not output the correct order I want.

```
<div id="test"></div>

 function hello(str){
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  this.eat = function(kind){
    text.innerHTML += "<p>Eat "+ kind + "</p>";
    return this;
  }
  this.sleep = function(delay){
    setTimeout(function(){
      text.innerHTML += "<p>Sleep "+delay + "</p>";
    }, delay);
    return this;
  }
  text.innerHTML += "<p>Hello, "+ str + "</p>";
  return this;
}
var test = hello("guy").sleep(3000).eat("dinner"); 
/* I want an output as: 
      Hello, guy -> (wait 3 secs) Sleep 3000 -> Eat dinner
   But actually the output is:
      Hello, guy -> Eat dinner -> (wait 3 secs) Sleep 3000    
*/
```

Does anyone have any ideas on it? Shoud I use the prototype, or some other ways to deal with it? What's more, if I want to add another method,  named  `sleepFirst` in this object. When I call it like this:

```
var test2 = hello("boys").sleepFirst(2000).eat("lanch")
```

it outputs:
    (wait 2 secs) sleepFirst 2000 -> Hello, boys -> Eat lanch

What should I do?
(Postscript: I am a beginner in Web Development, maybe someone has asked a similar question before but I had searched for a long time and can't find it out T^T I am a Chinese guy and sorry that my English may seem not so good. Thanks  ~~)

Comment: Interesting question. JS is asynchronous, so one way to go about it would be to add a callback to your sleep method, although that wouldn't be a chain then. Another way would be a queue system http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365318/delay-to-next-function-in-method-chain

Comment: @ArK  Oh Yes! The way of queue is workable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RobG convinced me to rewrite your piece of code using a real object definition. JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg009z8g/1/).

```
var sleeper = {
    text: document.getElementById("text"),
    eat: function (kind) {
        text.innerHTML += "<p>Eat " + kind + "</p>";
        return this;
    },
    sleep: function (delay, func, param) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            func(param);
            //text.innerHTML += "<p>Sleep " + delay + "</p>";
        }, delay);
        return this;
    },
    hello: function (str) {
        text.innerHTML += "<p>Hello, " + str + "</p>";
        return this;
    }
};

sleeper.hello("guy").sleep(3000, sleeper.eat, "dinner");
```

It's way much better. But this way you won't be abble to perform a chain of more than one call.

Comment: Note that *this* references the global object, likely that isn't what you're expecting, `this.sleep = ...;` is creating a global property, and you keep returning *this*, which is the global object, so your code is equivalent to `hello('guy'); sleep(...);`. Try it.

Comment: [edited cause you edited your answers.] You're right, I just modified this code to make it _working_, not _efficient_.

Comment: @Amessihel  Thank you! Also I've been suggested that I can use a queue  to deal with that, and I find it is a workable way  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365318/delay-to-next-function-in-method-chain)

Comment: Yep I saw it ! You can also buid a function this way : `function sleepyRun(delay1, call1, delay2, call2, ...)` You can manage functions with unlimited arguments. See [https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Fonctions/arguments](this) if you want to check out this way.